# Fetch daily data for each variable using mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I've a function which objective is to fetch daily data for each variable on a column on a `data.frame`. Range is a complete month, but could be any other range.

My `df` has a column `unit_id`,  so I need my function to take the first `id` of col `unit_id` and fetch the data for every single date of `march`.

```
| unit | unit_id |
|:-----:|----------|
|  AE   |    123   |
|  AD   |    456   |
|  AN   |    789   |
```

But right now, my function loops the ids in `unit_id` col. So as I've 3 `ids`, the 4th day the function uses the *1st id* again, and then for the 5th day uses the `2nd id` and so on. And this repeats until the last day of the month.

**I need it to use each id for every day of the month.**

**code:**

```
my_dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-03-31"), by = 1)

my_fetch <- function(unit, unit_id, d) {


  df <- google_analytics(unit_id,
                         date_range = c(d, d),
                         metrics = c("totalEvents"),
                         dimensions = c("ga:date", "ga:eventCategory", "ga:eventAction", "ga:eventLabel"),
                         anti_sample = TRUE)

  df$unidad_de_negocio <- unit


  filename <- paste0(unit, "-", "total-events", "-", d, ".csv")
  path <- "D:\\america\\costos_protv\\total_events"
  write.csv(df, file.path(path, filename), row.names = FALSE)
  print(filename)
  rm(df)
  gc()


}




monthly_fetches <- mapply(my_fetch, df$unit,
                          df$unit_id,
                          my_dates, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

**Variation 2: By monthly ranges**

Thank you, Akrun. Your answer works.

I'ven trying to edit it, ot use it in this other similar scenario:

1.- Monthly starts and ends: Now the loops isn't a single day date, but has an start and end. I've called this `monthly_dates`

```
|    starts   |    ends    |
|:-----------:|------------|
|  2020-02-01 | 2020-02-29 |
|  2020-03-01 | 2020-03-31 |
```

I've tried to adapt the solution, but it is not working. May you see it and tell me why? Thank you.

```
monthly_fetches <- Map(function(x, y) 
                   lapply(monthly_dates, function(d1, d2) my_fetch(x, y, monthly_dates$starts, monthly_dates$ends)))
```

**Main function adapted to use 2 dates (start "d1" and end "d2"):**

```
my_fetch <- function(udn, udn_id, d1, d2) {

    df <- google_analytics(udn_id,
                           date_range = c(d1, d2),
                           metrics = c("totalEvents"),
                           dimensions = c("ga:month"),
                           anti_sample = TRUE)

    df$udn <- udn
    df$udn_id <- udn_id

    df

}
```

** Code to make the monthly date ranges:**

```
make_date_ranges <- function(start, end){

  starts <- seq(from = start,
                to =  Sys.Date()-1 ,
                by = "1 month")

  ends <- c((seq(from = add_months(start, 1),
                 to = end,
                 by = "1 month" ))-1,
            (Sys.Date()-1))

  data.frame(starts,ends)

}

## useage
monthly_dates <- make_date_ranges(as.Date("2020-02-01"), Sys.Date())
```

**Update 1:**

***dput(monthly_fetches[1])***

```
list(AE = list(structure(list(month = "02", totalEvents = 19670334, 
    udn = "AE", udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(
    list(totalEvents = "19670334")), minimums = list(list(totalEvents = "19670334")), maximums = list(
    list(totalEvents = "19670334")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(month = "03", totalEvents = 19765253, udn = "AE", 
        udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(list(
        totalEvents = "19765253")), minimums = list(list(totalEvents = "19765253")), maximums = list(
        list(totalEvents = "19765253")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(month = "04", totalEvents = 1319087, udn = "AE", 
        udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(list(
        totalEvents = "1319087")), minimums = list(list(totalEvents = "1319087")), maximums = list(
        list(totalEvents = "1319087")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame")))
```

**Update 2:**

***dput(monthly_fetches[[1]])***

```
list(structure(list(month = "02", totalEvents = 19670334, udn = "AE", 
    udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(list(totalEvents = "19670334")), minimums = list(
    list(totalEvents = "19670334")), maximums = list(list(totalEvents = "19670334")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(month = "03", totalEvents = 19765253, udn = "AE", 
        udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(list(
        totalEvents = "19765253")), minimums = list(list(totalEvents = "19765253")), maximums = list(
        list(totalEvents = "19765253")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(month = "04", totalEvents = 1319087, udn = "AE", 
        udn_id = 74415341), row.names = 1L, totals = list(list(
        totalEvents = "1319087")), minimums = list(list(totalEvents = "1319087")), maximums = list(
        list(totalEvents = "1319087")), isDataGolden = TRUE, rowCount = 1L, class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `rm(df)` is not needed as *df* goes out of scope when function process ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Map/mapply` requires all arguments to be of same length and 'df' with number of rows of 3 and 'my_dates' length 31, one option is to loop over the 'df', columns and then do a further loop inside the `Map/mapply`

```
monthly_fetches <- Map(function(x, y) 
                 lapply(my_dates, function(date) my_fetch(x, y, date)),
                    df$unit, d$unit_id)
```

---

Or we can have outer loop for 'my_dates'

```
lapply(my_dates, function(date) Map(my_fetch, df$unit, df$unit_id, date))
```

#### Update

If we need to pass two columns, use `Map`

```
Map(function(start, end) 
  Map(my_fetch, df$unit, df$unit_id, start, end),  
            monthly_dates$starts, monthly_dates$ends))
```

Or

```
monthly_fetches <- Map(function(x, y) Map(function(start, end) 
   my_fetch(x, y, start, end),
      monthly_dates$starts, monthly_dates$ends), df$unit, df$unit_id)
```

Then `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(monthly_fetches, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))
```

Or use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(monthly_fetches, bind_rows, .id = 'grp')
```

Comment: please see my updated question. I'm trying to modify a little bit you answer to take an start and end dates for each fetch. `monthly_fetches` returns a list of 0. May you tell me why? I think I'm missing on my `Map` and `lapply functions`.

Comment: @arkun when I do: `total <- do.call(rbind, monthly_fetches)` with any of the options provided, I'm getting a matrix. When a data frame, rbinded was expected.

Comment: @OmarGonzales  Here, you may need `Map(function(x) do.call(rbind, Map(function(start, end)  my_fetch(x, y, start, end),
      monthly_dates$starts, monthly_dates$ends)), df$unit, df$unit_id)` and then wrap `do.call(rbind` on top

Comment: got this error: `Error in (function (x)  : unused argument (dots[[2]][[1]])`

Comment: @OmarGonzales is it possible to update with `dput` of a  sisngle list

Comment: @OmarGonzales  i.e. `dput(monthly_fetches[[1]])`

Comment: @OmarGonzales try `do.call(rbind,lapply(monthly_fetches, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))`

Comment: @OmarGonzales based on your `dput`, it is working for me